# Allow user to download a file generated by Java applet using Javascript API

Tags: java, javascript, applet, download

I have a Java applet embedded into a web page which generates a file that the user must download. I understand there is a way to do this by communicating with a Javascript API.

Could somebody please explain to me how to do it **this particular way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't allow file saving just yet, and the hacks that "work" need modern browser that understands data URI:s. In that case you would simply send the binary data as base64 and make the browser navigate to the [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) by setting `document.location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream...'` The download prompt would look like this in firefox:

http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/5080/octetstream.png

Flash allows for real download/save dialogs though so you could also look into that... or find out if java applets have that too.

Comment: +1 interesting technique.  I'd seen the data URI used for embedding images generated by applets, but not triggering a download.  Neat!

Answer (score 1):

If the user can be expected to have (or be willing to upgrade to) a Plug-In 2 architecture JRE (e.g. Sun's 1.6.0_10+)<sup>1</sup>, it is possible to launch the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  When an app. is launched using JWS, it can access the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) API, that offers file services that allow even sand-boxed code to save information to the local file-system.

Here is a [demo of the JNLP files services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

1. That is if the applet needs to be embedded.  JWS could launch applets free-floating since it was introduced in 1.2.